# Grub install fails while installing Ubuntu on RAID

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, raid, grub

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 9.10 using the alternate install CD, but I keep getting stuck.  I get through the first few steps of the install process easily enough (telling it what partition to install to, what user ID and password to create, time zone, etc.), but then it suddenly pops up a menu asking me what the next step in the install process is.  It has "Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk" selected by default.  When I select it, it goes to another screen with a progress bar and a label "Installing the 'grub2' package."  The progress bar gets to 16%, and then I get returned to the same menu.  No matter how many times I try to install grub, the exact same thing happens.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a two disk RAID-1 array.  This is the RAID card I'm using: http://www.siig.com/ViewProduct.aspx?pn=SC-SAER12-S2.  Any ideas what may be causing this to happen and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: that card uses a [SiI3132 chip](http://www.siliconimage.com/products/product.aspx?pid=32); it's a SATA controller, not hardware RAID.  you're better off using software RAID under Linux instead of the fakeRAID stuff.

Comment: @mgpyone: Thanks!  I still had to fiddle with some stuff the document didn't mention to get it to work, but it set me in the right direction.  Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you should troubleshoot with this [FakeRaidHowto Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto#Ubuntu%209.10%20%28%20Karmic%20Koala%29).